# Ruby: search filename for keyword

Tags: ruby

I am writing a case statement in ruby that will take the current filename and see if the filename includes a particular word, but I keep running into errors with my code.

```
file = File.basename(__FILE__)
case file
when file.include? "daily"
  HtmlCache.delete_all "daily = 1"
when file.include? "weekly"
  HtmlCache.delete_all "weekly = 1"
end
```

Anyone know how to search the filename for a particular word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if` instead of `case`. You have just wrong syntax.

```
file = File.basename(__FILE__)
if file.include? "daily"
  HtmlCache.delete_all "daily = 1"
elsif file.include? "weekly"
  HtmlCache.delete_all "weekly = 1"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
file = File.basename(__FILE__)
case file
when /daily/
  HtmlCache.delete_all "daily = 1"
when /weekly/
  HtmlCache.delete_all "weekly = 1"
end
```

Ruby's `case` statement matches using `===` (so `case file when /daily/` invokes `/daily/ === file`), which works as you'd like on Regexes.